# How can I create a new object of the same class as an object I already have?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, introspection

I've an array which holds different kinds of objects: `UIButton`s, `UILabel`s, `UITableView`s, etc.

Is there any way that I can dynamically create these objects while looping through the array without using `if`/`else` conditions like below:

```
for (NSObject *obj in objectsArray)
{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
         UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [self.view addSubview:btn];
    }
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)obj;
        [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    }
}
```

Can we create objects like `UIButton *btn` or `UILabel *lbl` using reflection or something dynamically?

Comment: if the objects are already in the array why create them again ??

Comment: if the initializer are different (UIButton), you have to if/else.

Comment: Are the objects in the array instances or class objects?

Answer (score 0):

you could either do

```
for (Class _class in classArray) {
    id object = [[_class alloc] init];
}
```

or

```
for (NSString *className in classNameArray) {
    id object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
}
```

so you dont need Instances for the class-reference.

Comment: This assumes that the objects in the array are either strings representing class objects, or the classes themselves; from OP's code, that is not the case: the array contains _instances_.